# what is a good idea for manage and check pages permission?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have built a crm with  asp.net.I want to set and check

- some permission for some pages,
- some user controls,
- some panel ,
- some records in database .

please get me a good idea for manage and check this permission easily.

Comment: while u wait for the answers, look at how they did it in some open source .net cms'es like orchard: http://orchard.codeplex.com/releases/69668/download/288792

Comment: check the document at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649337.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Role Provider is a simple option. If however your permission structure can not be described by a list of roles, you will probably have to implement a custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using asp.net membership provider for pages.. while if you also need to apply checks on controls/panels you should have a look at this answer. it implements ControlAdapters to apply roles on controls.

[Role-based enabling/disabling of controls in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708489/role-based-enabling-disabling-of-controls-in-asp-net/8708579#8708579)

Regards.