# The best solution to customize page controls based on some roles and settings

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, customization, roles

I have several pages in asp.net  each with lots of controls. I Also have some roles in my application that each has some setting options. Now I want to prepare my page based on these settings. Maybe it’s not too clear, so please take a look at my example.

Example: There are some buttons, some textboxes, some datetime picker, and a chart in a page, now what I want is when a user sees this page, the controls appear and disappear based on the users  role. An important thing is that I don’t want to have only visible and invisible controls, in some scenarios I need to show controls with some customizations. For example change chart data source, limit selecting date time and so on.

The first solution that I can think of, is saving the settings in database and after visiting the page by user, the settings fetch from database and based on those, I can customize the controls with conditional phrases (if and else). But I suppose it is not a good approach and my page will get very messy.

Please help me with any better solutions and if you know good references about it, please let me know.

Comment: Take a look at the webpart and webpartmanager classes.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this link...use of `ControlAdapters` may help you...

[Role-based enabling/disabling of controls in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708489/role-based-enabling-disabling-of-controls-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

You must use Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

A. When user login to your application, you attach his identity to thread, for example

```
string[] rolesArray = .....; //Get roles from dataBase by identity.
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new YourCustomPrincipal(new YourCustomIdentity("YouName", "..."), rolesArray);
```

B. And when you navige about your application you test Thread.CurrentPrincipal

```
IPrincipal threadPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
if(threadPrincipal.Roles.Contains("roleTest"))
{
  //Adjust your control
}
```