# Hide a specific navigation menu items from anonymous users

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I Want to hide some navigation menu items located in the master page from anonymous users,
and hide other items from users according to thier roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres is very good way of achieving this.You can use `Control adapters` to achieve this.
Please have a look at following thread..

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708489/role-based-enabling-disabling-of-controls-in-asp-net
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [LoginView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loginview). Just put any content you need invisible to anonymous users in the `<LoggedInTemplate>`:

```
<asp:LoginView
    runat="server">
        <AnonymousTemplate>
            <!-- anonymous users see this -->
        </AnonymousTemplate>
        <LoggedInTemplate>
            <!-- only registered, logged in users see this -->
        </LoggedInTemplate>
```